# React MuiFileInput validation for file upload displays error even after the file is selected

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a material ui design of a input type="file". How to validate the file and display the error message?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { MuiFileInput } from "mui-file-input";

export default function App() {
  const {  register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors },} = useForm();
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);
  const handleFile = (event) => {
    setFile(event);
  };
  
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.file?.name));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <MuiFileInput sx={{ margin: 2 }}
        {...register("uploadFile", 
          {required: "Please select an image."},
        )}
        onChange= {handleFile}
        value={file}
        label="Upload Image" placeholder='Select a file'
        error={Boolean(errors.uploadFile)}
        helperText={errors.uploadFile?.message}
      />
      <Button type="submit" variant="contained" sx={{ margin: 2 }}>Submit</Button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

The error is displayed even after the file is selected

[image]

How to eliminate this error after file selection?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Value props of input and just simply use MUI TextField and Style it

```
<TextField label="Upload Image" name="uploadImage"  sx={{ margin: 2 }} 
          placeholder="Select a file"
          onChange={handleFile} type="file" 
          
          {...register("uploadImage", {
            required: "Please select a file",
          })}
          error={Boolean(errors.uploadImage)}
          helperText={errors.uploadImage?.message}
        />
```

Comment: This works good, but I want it to be implemented in mui design <MuiFileInput > component.

Answer (score 0):

add `reset` where you included `useForm` and reset file field before selecting new file, this will reset error before selecting new file, and show error only if you did not select new file.

```html
....

export default function App() {
  const {  register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm();
  
  ....
  
   const handleFile = (event) => {
      reset({
        'uploadFile': null
      });
      setFile(event);
    };
```

[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/register-forked-xguwme?file=/src/App.js) has a working example !

Comment: The error returns back  when submit button is pressed, which prevents the FORM from submitting. the working example also has this issue

Comment: change `onSubmit` like this `{handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}` and add `const onError = (errors, e) => console.log(errors, e);` this shows no error, that means form doesn't have error, its `MuiFileInput`  component is not behaving correctly.